# Update files on FTP server folder hierarchy with local files from a single folder

Tags: ftp

I have a little-big problem. I need to copy/overwrite JPG files from my local FOLDER to server FOLDERS.

Is there a way to search and match JPG files on SERVER with my files on LOCAL and overwrite them in server folders? I do it manually and it takes lot of time.

There are 50 000 JPGs on server and I need to overwrite 20 000 of them in short time.

Many thanks for answers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic way to do your very specific task. You have to script it.

If you are on Windows, it's rather trivial to write a [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) for this, using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) and its [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles):

```powershell
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}

$remotePath = "/remote/path";
$localPath = "C:\local\Path";

# Connect
Write-Host "Connecting..."
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.SessionLogPath = "upload.log"
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Enumerate remote files
$fileInfos =
    $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        $remotePath, "*.*", [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::AllDirectories)

# And look for a matching local file for each of them
foreach ($fileInfo in $fileInfos)
{
    $localFilePath = (Join-Path $localPath $fileInfo.Name)
    if (Test-Path $localFilePath)
    {
        Write-Host ("Found local file $localFilePath matching remote file " +
            "$($fileInfo.FullName), overwriting..."
        # Command-out this line with # for a dry-run
        $session.PutFiles($localFilePath, $fileInfo.FullName).Check()
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host ("Found no local file matching remote file " +
            "$($fileInfo.FullName), skipping..."
    }
}

Write-Host "Done"
```

Save the script to a file (`SortOutFiles.ps1`), extract a contents of [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) package along with the script, and run it like:

```
C:\myscript>powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File SortOutFiles.ps1
Connecting...
Found local file C:\local\path\aaa.txt matching remote file /remote/path/1/aaa.txt, overwritting...
Found local file C:\local\path\bbb.txt matching remote file /remote/path/2/bbb.txt, overwritting...
Found local file C:\local\path\ccc.txt matching remote file /remote/path/ccc.txt, overwritting...
Done
```

You can first dry-run the script by commenting out the line with `$session.PutFiles` call.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

download "Filezilla"... Upload your local files (all 50000 images).. If a image is already there in server,, it will ask you options.. select 'overwrite' and use 'apply for all'...

Comment: But on server are jpgs in diferent folders. On my local are only jpegs with same names of jpgs files. Filezilla can copy my local jpegs to right folders?